# Peer to peer/adaptive payments with paypal

Tags: ios, api, paypal, sdk, payment

I'm trying to implement a PoC in iOS related with peer to peer payments.
I'm in the initial stage of this project and my first idea was the adaptive payments by PayPal.

This is the scenario:

- User A (normal user) sends money to User B (normal user)

Both users are normal users, they are not premium or business. The idea is send money to a friend/familiar.

On my research I found this link related with adaptive payments

Adaptive Doc: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/

Reading the doc, seems that these payments are only for premium or business users... and I'm not really sure if PayPal supports this kind of payments between non premium users.

To be honest, I'm looking just peer to peer payment (kind of transfer) more than a real payment between a merchant/vendor and users. I think that is more like sending money by email.

So my questions are: 
- Is there any way to implement this kind of payments between normal users in PayPay? Should I use the adaptive payments API or this is supported in other API?
- Do you know if the adaptive API is used for the send money by email?
- Do you recommend any other companies for this kind of p2p payment?

Thans in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Adaptive Payments (Pay API) is the way to go.  The app owner would need to be a business account, but then the app could send payments between two personal accounts no problem.

Comment: @Alexsanz I'm trying something similar, did this work out for you?