# Peer to peer payments in iOS

Tags: ios, paypal, payment

I am developing a shopping platform in iOS, where independent buyers and sellers exist simultaneously. The products are real world objects or services. I need to implement the financial structure such that with every purchase between the buyer and seller, payments go through the app owner. The need for that is because the app owner will deduct a certain cut from each transaction.

In all my research, I understand that in app purchases is out of the option because each product in the app will be added dynamically, with any price range. So I will have to implement some other means of payment i.e. PayPal or alike.

My first question is that is such a financial transaction possible in iOS apps? I found an app 'Square Cash' on iTunes which I believe does what I'm trying to do. (ref: [Square Cash on itunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/square-cash-send-money-for/id711923939?mt=8)) Square cash lets users transfer cash via the app amongst each other but they're doing it without any charges.

My second question is how do I implement such a payment mechanism? I found a SO post related to my problem: [Peer to peer/adaptive payments with paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27138735/peer-to-peer-adaptive-payments-with-paypal) but this question has been closed without a conclusive solution. Also, would the app owner need to pay any fee to paypal for this payment structure?

I am fairly new to iOS applications, let alone payment methods in iOS apps. Any pointer in the right direction will be much appreciated. Thanks